# When I join a table to a shapefile and then export it the titles of the columns are transformed to data1, data2

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, table

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1

The table is in an excel format that i import through  "add vector" and the shapefile is a polygone

I join the attributes by right clicking the polygone-->properties-->join
Then once done if i look at the attributes table of the polygone everything is fine 
But when i do save as shapefile and add the new layer, all the data of the attribute table is there expect that the titles of the columns become data1, data2

Does anyone knows how to fix it? or maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to specify it s when i export it to a new shapefile. also the table is an excel format. thx

Comment: You can (and probably should) edit your post (instead of adding comments). Short questions are discouraged on this site. Try to be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .dbf of a shapefile has certain limits on the columns names, e.g. number of characters needs to be <11 characters, and that there cannot be spaces in the column names.  I'm guessing when you export out to a new shapefile the function finds these errors and attempts to generate a valid column name.

Make sure your column names are shapefile friendly before performing the join.